# Apache Karaf Rest Service Issue

Tags: java, osgi, apache-karaf

I am having a WAB application which is just having only one html file, and its working fine. the code is available on the below git link

https://github.com/vineethvnair0/Karaf/tree/master/first-wab

Now I want to define a rest service in the wab, with the same context root as my web app for example like below.

http://localhost:8181/first-wab/rest/hello

Please let me know how can i do it?

Answer (score 0):

Simply add a CXF servlet to the web.xml. The exact solution depends on how you expose your Rest endpoints. Do you plan to use spring?

Comment: I am not sure how can i add a rest service inside my WAB. I have a working rest application in the link https://github.com/vineethvnair0/Karaf/tree/master/first-rest.

Can you please tell me how to add it in my WAB?

Comment: Ah .. so you want to use blueprint. It is not possible to create a REST service outside of the WAB bundle and still have it in the same web context. 
For the same context it might work using http://aries.apache.org/modules/blueprintweb.html but I never tested this.

Comment: so all i need to do is create a rest in my wab and then add the configuration

<listener>
      <listener-class>org.apache.aries.blueprint.web.BlueprintContextListener</listener-class>
  </listener>
in my web.xml?

Comment: I am not sure if it works. In the worst case you can still use the CXF servlet transport (by using a non absolute service address like /myservice). It will make sure that CXF uses the HTTPService offered by karaf. So at least you can work with the default HTTP port.